# Django: How can I create a model from a POST request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

To put it on context, I would like to let users create models using a form in the templates. That way the can create multiple different models if necessary.

Example: Let's say, as an user I want to create a form that takes the name and phone number of a person. Then I'd like to create another form that takes a name, a time and a phone number.

What would be the best approach to doing this task?

Comment: Is it what you want ? "https://pypi.org/project/django-dynamic-model/"

Comment: It seems this might work, I'll do some testing and research. Thank you!